# Importing data into a master worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a doubt about my program to the VBA/EXCEL
I made a file called "MASTER WORKSHEET" with various data from a client, my goal is: To create a VBA to open any file in Excel and that I import chosen cells to fill out all data of the "MASTER WORKSHEET", for example, all excel file I open with the button "IMPORT DATA", it will automatically capture only those cells that I choose, but my program it captures but is with configuration problems on VALUE or NUMBER.

Comment: Example: I want to copy the cell "Y4" and I want to paste on the "MASTER WORKSHEET" the cell "J28"

Comment: _3.  Questions asking for "homework help" must include a **summary of the work you've done so far** to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._ -[Help Center: What's On Topic Here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) [Emphasis Mine]

Comment: Could you post the code?  The line about configuration problems I am not following.  Are you receiving an error, and on what line?

Comment: It's so broad and unclear I don't even know how to edit the title to make it more clear. (Normally I'd edit to take out the tag in the title...)

Comment: Sorry my colleagues, I will try to send again the matter. My main goal is: I want to copy "the cell that I want it from any file but the a condition that these cells are choosen, example; J1, J3, J8 and that these cells can be pasted on the "MASTER WORKSHEET" in A4, A5 and A6.

Comment: @BrunoSoares What code have you written so far?  Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: How can you show you my code @Chrismas007?

Comment: In order to show your code, use the "edit" link displayed immediately below the question.  You will then be able to copy/paste the relevant sections of your code into the question.  (After pasting it, press Ctrl-K to format it as code.)

Answer (score -2):

If your question is simply "how do I copy a cell from one place to another", an example would be:

```
Workbooks("Input Workbook").Worksheets("Input Worksheet").Range("J1").Copy(Workbooks("Master Workbook").Worksheets("Master Worksheet").Range("A4"))
```

If you just want to copy the value, without the formula and formatting, you could use

```
Workbooks("Master Workbook").Worksheets("Master Worksheet").Range("A4").Value = Workbooks("Input Workbook").Worksheets("Input Worksheet").Range("J1").Value
```

Obviously, the workbook, sheet, and range names need to be changed to your particular situation.

Comment: I understand it, but do you think that any file when I choose to import the "chosen files"? independent of the file name?

Comment: the "MASTER WORKSHEET" I would have the name, but the files that I open will be many, how can I get all them?

Comment: @BrunoSoares - if your code is looping through many files you most probably have a string variable specifying the name of the file it is currently processing.  From that string you can create another string which is just the workbook name (i.e. usually just the full filename without the path) and that string variable can then be used instead of "Input Workbook".  Similarly, if you are looping through many worksheets you probably have a string variable specifying the name of the worksheet currently being processed, which can then be used instead of "Input Worksheet".

Comment: @BrunoSoares - If your question is more complicated than just "how do I copy one cell to another location", paste the part of your code that is causing the issue into the question, and let us know what the problem is.

Comment: I tried to write like this; ActiveSheet.Range("b5").Value, but on the my file "MASTER WORKSHEET" it is not showing the correct date. While I'm not getting send the code here